# Regex redefinition error

Tags: python, regex, scripting

I am using python, and run into some redefinition error, I know they are redefinition but logically its not possible to reach that since its an or. Is there a way to get around this? I appreciate for any help in advance

/python-2.5/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 233, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'id' as group 9; was group 6

```
import re

DOB_RE =  "(^|;)DOB +(?P<dob>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})"
ID_RE =   "(^|;)ID +(?P<id>[A-Z0-9]{12})"
INFO_RE = "- (?P<info>.*)"

PERSON_RE = "((" + DOB_RE + ".*" + ID_RE +  ")|(" + \
                   ID_RE  + ".*" + DOB_RE + ")|(" + \
                   DOB_RE + "|" + ID_RE + ")).*(" + INFO_RE + ")*"

PARSER = re.compile(PERSON_RE)

samplestr1 = garbage;DOB 10-10-2010;more garbage\nID PARI12345678;more garbage
samplestr2 = garbage;ID PARI12345678;more garbage\nDOB 10-10-2010;more garbage
samplestr3 = garbage;DOB 10-10-2010
samplestr4 = garbage;ID PARI12345678;more garbage- I am cool
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression syntax simply does not allow multiple occurrences of identically-named groups -- groups that aren't "reached" are defined to be "empty" (None) on a match.

So you have to change those names e.g. to `dob0`, `dob1`, `dob2` and `id0`, `id1`, `id2` (then you can easily "collapse" these sets of keys to make the dict you actually want after you have a groups dictionary from a match).

E.g., make the `DOB_RE` a function instead of a constant, say:

```
def DOB_RE(i): return "(^|;)DOB +(?P<dob%s>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})" % i
```

and similarly for the others, and change the three occurrences of `DOB_RE` in the statement where you compute `PERSON_RE` to `DOB_RE(0)`, `DOB_RE(1)` etc (and similarly for the others).

Answer (score 2):

I was originally going to post a pyparsing example using the Each class (which picks out expressions that can be in any order), but then I saw that there was intermixed garbage, so searching through your string using `searchString` seemed a better fit.  This intrigued me because `searchString` returns a sequence of ParseResults, one for each match (including any corresponding named results).  So I thought, "What if I combine the returned ParseResults using sum - what a hack!", er, "How novel!"  So here's a never-before-seen pyparsing hack:

```
from pyparsing import *
# define the separate expressions to be matched, with results names
dob_ref = "DOB" + Regex(r"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}")("dob")
id_ref = "ID" + Word(alphanums,exact=12)("id")
info_ref = "-" + restOfLine("info")

# create an overall expression
person_data = dob_ref | id_ref | info_ref

for test in (samplestr1,samplestr2,samplestr3,samplestr4,):
    # retrieve a list of separate matches
    separate_results = person_data.searchString(test)

    # combine the results using sum
    # (NO ONE HAS EVER DONE THIS BEFORE!)
    person = sum(separate_results, ParseResults([]))

    # now we have a uber-ParseResults object!
    print person.id
    print person.dump()
    print
```

Giving this output:

```
PARI12345678
['DOB', '10-10-2010', 'ID', 'PARI12345678']
- dob: 10-10-2010
- id: PARI12345678

PARI12345678
['ID', 'PARI12345678', 'DOB', '10-10-2010']
- dob: 10-10-2010
- id: PARI12345678


['DOB', '10-10-2010']
- dob: 10-10-2010

PARI12345678
['ID', 'PARI12345678', '-', ' I am cool']
- id: PARI12345678
- info:  I am cool
```

But I do also speak regex.  Here is a similar approach using re's.

```
import re

# define each individual re, with group names
dobRE = r"DOB +(?P<dob>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})"
idRE = r"ID +(?P<id>[A-Z0-9]{12})"
infoRE = r"- (?P<info>.*)"

# one re to rule them all
person_dataRE = re.compile('|'.join([dobRE, idRE, infoRE]))

# using findall with person_dataRE will return a 3-tuple, so let's create 
# a tuple-merger
merge = lambda a,b : tuple(aa or bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b))

# let's create a Person class to collect the different data bits 
# (or if you are running Py2.6, use a namedtuple
class Person:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.dob, self.id, self.info = args
    def __str__(self):
        return "- id: %s\n- dob: %s\n- info: %s" % (self.id, self.dob, self.info)

for test in (samplestr1,samplestr2,samplestr3,samplestr4,):
    # could have used reduce here, but let's err on the side of explicity
    persontuple = ('','','')
    for data in person_dataRE.findall(test):
        persontuple = merge(persontuple,data)

    # make a person
    person = Person(*persontuple)

    # print out the collected results
    print person.id
    print person
    print
```

With this output:

```
PARI12345678
- id: PARI12345678
- dob: 10-10-2010
- info: 

PARI12345678
- id: PARI12345678
- dob: 10-10-2010
- info: 


- id: 
- dob: 10-10-2010
- info: 

PARI12345678
- id: PARI12345678
- dob: 
- info: I am cool
```

Comment: @Paul: Is pyparsing also available for Python 3?

Comment: @Tim: yes, the current release include a pyparsing_py3 module that will be installed if you are running Python 3 (there is a benign installation error, which I will fix in the next release).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in this case it is better to loop through a list of regular expressions.

```
>>> strs=[
... "garbage;DOB 10-10-2010;more garbage\nID PARI12345678;more garbage",
... "garbage;ID PARI12345678;more garbage\nDOB 10-10-2010;more garbage",
... "garbage;DOB 10-10-2010",
... "garbage;ID PARI12345678;more garbage- I am cool"]
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> DOB_RE =  "(^|;|\n)DOB +(?P<dob>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})"
>>> ID_RE =   "(^|;|\n)ID +(?P<id>[A-Z0-9]{12})"
>>> INFO_RE = "(- (?P<info>.*))?"
>>> 
>>> REGEX = map(re.compile,[DOB_RE + ".*" + ID_RE + "[^-]*" + INFO_RE,
...                         ID_RE + ".*" + DOB_RE + "[^-]*" + INFO_RE,
...                         DOB_RE + "[^-]*" + INFO_RE,
...                         ID_RE + "[^-]*" + INFO_RE])
>>> 
>>> def get_person(s):
...     for regex in REGEX:
...         res = re.search(regex,s)
...         if res:
...             return res.groupdict()
... 
>>> for s in strs:
...     print get_person(s)
... 
{'dob': '10-10-2010', 'info': None, 'id': 'PARI12345678'}
{'dob': '10-10-2010', 'info': None, 'id': 'PARI12345678'}
{'dob': '10-10-2010', 'info': None}
{'info': 'I am cool', 'id': 'PARI12345678'}
```